# Reactive mongo db.command deprecation

Tags: mongodb, reactivemongo

I have used db.command function to do mostly count requests, but with new update I have found that this function is depreaceted with following message that I not understand:

consider using reactivemongo.api.commands along with `GenericDB.runCommand` methods

I have not found migration guide for this deprecation.

What is actually alternative now for this code ?

```
val totalFuture: Future[Int] = db.command(
  Count(
    "collection",
    Some(BSONFormats.toBSON(Json.obj("key"->"value")).get.asInstanceOf[BSONDocument])
  )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the [documentation](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/documentation/advanced-topics/commands.html), you will see that a `.count` operation is now directly available on collection, and you will see example of `RawCommand` usage for not yet implemented commands.

Comment: Thank you for pointing to the documentation that explains the new way of running this. I must say, even if it's written in the docs, it hadn't beed very clear how to fix the warning from the compiler message.